# UPDATE a table using SELECT

Tags: python, mysql, sql

inserted some data into a table using this:

```
INSERT INTO contactos (nombre_contacto,
        apellido_contacto,celular_contacto,email_contacto,detalle_contacto,
        id_empresa)
        VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s,(SELECT id_empresa FROM empresas
                  WHERE razon_social = %s))
```

and i tried to updata the data using this:

```
UPDATE contactos
        SET nombre_contacto=%s,
            apellido_contacto=%s,
            celular_contacto=%s,
            email_contacto=%s,
            detalle_contacto=%s
            id_empresa=(SELECT id_empresa FROM empresas
                      WHERE razon_social = %s)
```

It didnt worked so I used this:

```
    UPDATE contactos
            SET nombre_contacto='Jessica',
                apellido_contacto='Munoz',
                celular_contacto='123456',
                email_contacto='jesica.munoz',
                detalle_contacto='mama'
                contactos.id_empresa= empresas.id_empresa
                INSERT (ontactos.id_empresa)
                VALUES(SELECT id_empresa FROM empresas
WHERE razon_social = 'andrea sa')
            WHERE id_contacto='3'
```

I also tried updating it using FROM but I am new to sql and don't really understand how it works.
Any help would be amazing. Thanks!

Comment: edit your question to show (as text, not an image) output of `show create table contactos` and `show create table empresas`.  and please explain what you want your UPDATE to do: update one row?  update all rows with the id_empresa for a given razon_social? something else?

Comment: I would guess that your first UPDATE is closest to what you want, only missing a `WHERE id_contacto=3` to tell it what row to update

Comment: Is there `python` anywhere in the question, that you tagged it?

Answer (score 0):

> inserted some data into a table using this:
>
> ```sql
> INSERT INTO contactos (nombre_contacto,
>        apellido_contacto,celular_contacto,email_contacto,detalle_contacto,
>        id_empresa)
>        VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s,(SELECT id_empresa FROM empresas
>                  WHERE razon_social = %s))
> ```

Use `INSERT .. SELECT`:

```sql
INSERT INTO contactos (nombre_contacto, apellido_contacto, celular_contacto, 
                       email_contacto, detalle_contacto, id_empresa)
SELECT %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, id_empresa 
FROM empresas
WHERE razon_social = %s;
```

> and i tried to updata the data using this:
>
> ```sql
> UPDATE contactos
>        SET nombre_contacto=%s,
>            apellido_contacto=%s,
>            celular_contacto=%s,
>            email_contacto=%s,
>            detalle_contacto=%s
>            id_empresa=(SELECT id_empresa FROM empresas
>                      WHERE razon_social = %s)
> ```

Use multiple-table UPDATE:

```sql
UPDATE contactos
CROSS JOIN (SELECT id_empresa 
            FROM empresas
            WHERE razon_social = %s) xxx
SET nombre_contacto=%s,
    apellido_contacto=%s,
    celular_contacto=%s,
    email_contacto=%s,
    detalle_contacto=%s
    id_empresa=xxx.id_empresa;
```

Pay attention - the parameters order is changed.

Comment: why do you say "This is wrong."? it works just fine; your proposed replacement has different behavior (possibly wanted, possibly unwanted) when the subquery returns 0 rows or more than one row

Comment: @ysth Ok, the sentence removed. PS. But I think that this is "possibly wanted" ideologically and, maybe, even provides the FK relation.